# Declaring a hashmap inside a method

Tags: java, multithreading

Local variables are thread safe in Java. Is using a `hashmap` declared inside a method thread safe?
For Example-

```
void usingHashMap()
{
    HashMap<Integer> map = new HashMap<integer>();
}
```

Comment: That one line of code does two things, and you hide the distinction between them when you use one word, "declared," to describe them both.  That line declares a variable, and it also creates a new object.  The language guarantees that every invocation of the function gets its own instance of the variable, but it's up to you to make sure that the object is not shared with other threads.  As long as the only references to the new HashMap object are args and locals, everything will be fine; but if you assign it to a field that could be seen by other threads, then you could be headed for trouble.

Answer (score 5):

When two threads run the same method here `usingHashMap()`, they are in no way way related. Each `thread` will create its own version of every local variable, and these variables will not interact with each other in any way

If variables aren't local,then they are attached to the instance. In this case, two threads running the same method both see the one variable, and this isn't threadsafe.

```
public class usingHashMapNotThreadSafe {
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    public int work() {
        //manipulating the hashmap here
    }
}

public class usingHashMapThreadSafe {
    public int worksafe() {
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        //manipulating the hashmap here
    }
}
```

While `usingHashMapNotThreadSafe` two threads running on the same instance of `usingHashMapNotThreadSafe` will see the same x. This could be dangerous, because the threads are trying to change `map`! In the second, two threads running on the same instance of `usingHashMapThreadSafe` will see totally different versions of x, and can't effect each other.

Comment: @Francis- Thanks.So if one has to choose a collection between 'hashtabe' and 'hashmap', then in this scenario 'hashmap' would be a better choice.?

Comment: The key point is that the `HashMap` must be externally synchronized rather than relying on the internal synchronized methods. In `Hashtable` Synchronizing every method should take care of any concurrency problems makes it very much worse for threaded applications. You should try `ConcurrentMap` if you think you are not upto external synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the reference to the HashMap object is not published (is not passed to another method), it is threadsafe. 

The same applies to the keys/values stored in the map. They need to be either immutable (cannot change their states after being created) or used only within this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think to ensure complete concurrency, a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) should be used in any case. Even if it is local in scope. `ConcurrentHashMap` implements `ConcurrentMap`. The partitioning is essentially an attempt, as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to:

*The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without contention. Because placement in hash tables is essentially random, the actual concurrency will vary. Ideally, you should choose a value to accommodate as many threads as will ever concurrently modify the table. Using a significantly higher value than you need can waste space and time, and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention.*

Comment: This would be waste of resources, because ConcurrentHashMap is internally partitioned in order to allow efficient concurrent modifications. Using ConcurrentHashMap may also suggest, that we try to deal with multi-threading issues decreasing readability of the code.